# How to change historical data on a history table

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm, tree

I have a table with tree like structure and dates to track changes(child, parent, root, effective_date, expire_date, status). 
But now I want to change the historical data also. 
For example the table now has these 3 records,

```
1 c1    p1    r1    2018-09-11    2018-09-13    NA 
2 c1    p2    r2    2018-09-13    2018-09-15    NA 
3 c1    p3    r3    2018-09-15    9999-12-01    A
```

now we want to change the parent of "c1" to "p4" with root of "r4" between "2018-09-12" and "2018-09-14". so the table will be like this,

```
1 c1    p1    r1    2018-09-11    2018-09-12    NA 
2 c1    p4    r4    2018-09-12    2018-09-14    NA 
3 c1    p2    r2    2018-09-14    2018-09-15    NA 
4 c1    p3    r3    2018-09-15    9999-12-01    A
```

In regards to performance what's the best design for this problem?

Comment: I do not get it.
history table shows the history of the data in the past. Why do you want to manipulate the data? If you have not done something in the past, you can not say that you did it. I do not think it would be possible in Oracle

Comment: As an alternative, you can build your own log mechanism that writes the changes to a table.

Comment: @hotfix we use these grouping data and make reports based on them but for example after a year we find there was a mistake on them and want to fix data and making reports again.

Comment: Your data auditor should get some more grey hair if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to elaborate if your data model is correct, just answer the question. You need two `update`s on dates, one `insert` and optionally one `delete` to remove row(s) if new period covers whole previous period(s).

```
declare
  r data%rowtype; 
begin
  r.child  := 'c1';
  r.parent := 'p4';
  r.root   := 'r4';
  r.effective_date := date '2018-09-12';
  r.expire_date := date '2018-09-14';
  r.status := 'NA';

  delete from data 
    where r.effective_date <= effective_date and expire_date <= r.expire_date;
  update data set expire_date = r.effective_date 
    where expire_date between r.effective_date and r.expire_date;
  update data set effective_date = r.expire_date 
    where effective_date between r.effective_date and r.expire_date;
  insert into data values r;
end;
```

Table I used for test:

```
create table data(child, parent, root, effective_date, expire_date, status) as (
    select 'c1', 'p1', 'r1', date '2018-09-11', date '2018-09-13', 'NA' from dual union all 
    select 'c1', 'p2', 'r2', date '2018-09-13', date '2018-09-15', 'NA' from dual union all 
    select 'c1', 'p3', 'r3', date '2018-09-15', date '9999-12-01', 'A'  from dual );
```

These are simple operations, if you have indexes on dates they should be fast. You can combine two updates into one statment using `or` and `case when`, but I doubt it's crucial.

Comment: Thanks Ponder, but the problem is when c1 has a subtree and when we correct c1 parent that changes root, all of the descendants must change

Comment: OK. Maybe if you edit your query and show on example how this root changes applies to other rows we will be able to answer. It's probably update on select.